# Google showing "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt "

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, wordpress-theming, meta-tags

I create a web application and host this site using wordpress.When i search name in goole it is showing

> A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt

Why this is happening.Is there problem in metatag?

Comment: post robots.txt content if you don't find where robots.txt exists see this [WordPress Robots.txt](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-optimize-your-wordpress-robots-txt-for-seo/)

Answer (score 0):

Your site’s `robots.txt` file is disallowing crawling of the page you found in Google Search. This means Google’s bot won’t visit this page to read its content.

The `robots.txt` file exists at the URL `/robots.txt`, e.g., `http://example.com/robots.txt`.

You’ll want to look for and check any lines starting with `Disallow:`:

- **`Disallow:`** allows everything
- **`Disallow: /`** blocks everything
- **`Disallow: /a`** blocks every URL whose path starts with `/a`,
  e.g. `http://example.com/a`, `http://example.com/abc`, `http://example.com/a/b.html` etc.

Comment: where is robots.txt file generate.

Comment: How to change text in robots.txt file

Comment: @VijayKumarB: Did you try searching before? Should be easy to find out how to edit the robots.txt in WordPress. If you have a specific problem while trying it, you can ask a question here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the Yoast SEO plugin installed, you can find and edit the robots.txt file at
SEO > Tools > File Editor

If you use Google Search Console (highly recommended) then you can test your robots.txt file
Go to Crawl > robots.txt tester

GSC - https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en